# How to append values to ViewBag in controller .net core MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I have a load ViewBag in my controller which gets data from my SQL database like below.

```
ViewBag.students = context.Gen_list.Where(d => d.AppRole == "Leader")
                .Select(d => d.FullName).Distinct();
```

After executing above command, ViewBag.students have 2 values like below

```
[0] "Mike Igar"
[1] "Ram Barb"
```

Now within the controller I want to append 2 more values so that ViewBag.students will become like below,

```
[0] "Mike Igar"
[1] "Ram Barb"
[2] "Krish Sag"
[3] "Paul Dev"
```

I googled for more than 2 hours but couldn't figure out how to get above result. Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Instead of trying to add list to the ViewBag.Below I am adding the list to variable and than feeding it to ViewBag.

```
   var consultants = context.Gen_list.Where(d => d.AppRole == "Leader")
                 .Select(d => d.FullName).Distinct();ToList();

   List<string> weekend = new List<string> {"Krish Sag", "Paul Dev"};
    
   ViewBag.students = students.Concat(weekend);
```